# The Security to the Party [Part 14]

Tags: password

The Spaghetti dude just can't get enough of his parties... so there's yet another chance for you and your mate to steal the recipe.

The first guest arrives. The security says "3", and the guest replies "2".

The second guest arrives. The security says "4", and the guest replies "3".

The third guest arrives. The security says "5", and the guest replies "4".

You're friend thinks, this time the host really let his guard down. He approaches the security and they say "6", when he replies "5" they refuse entry and he runs off before they can release the elephant.

Another guest arrives. The security says "1", and the guest replies "2".

It's your turn now. You go up to the door and the security guard says "8". What do you reply?

Comment: @A E I just made part 15 which includes the elephant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The answer is 3
>
>  It's the number of sides the number shares with other numbers in a number cube
> 1 2 3
> 4 5 6
> 7 8 9

Comment: I can't figure out formatting with the spoiler tag, working on it.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Nice work! :) (Although I'd call it a square ;) ... numbers on a phone pad also work.)

Answer (score 1):

> Consider the mapping:
>  `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`
>  `2 3 2 3 4 2 3 4 5`
>  (where the top is the guard's prompt and the bottom is the response)
>  Then, the response for 8 is 4.

Comment: Interesting, but nope (neither the answer nor the method is correct). (As a rather vague hint, you would have gotten *one* - so far unknown - number correct by coincidence.)